# hook_user not being called for 'login' operation

Tags: drupal, hook

I've read in the drupal documentation that hook_user should be invoked for the login operation. To test this I've added a call to `drupal_set_message` at the top of my modules hook implementation and the only message I'm receiving is a call with 'load' as the $op.

I've confirmed that drupal_set_message can be called multiple times and it doesn't erase the previous message, so I'm confident that hook_user is only being invoked the one time.

Any good reasons for why hook_user isn't being invoked with 'login' as an operation when I'm logging in?

Drupal version is 6 and my module is called "favequest_favorites" its implementation of hook_user (for testing purposes) is:

```
function favequest_favorites_user($op, &$edit, &$user, $caterogy=NULL) {
  drupal_set_message($op);
}
```

Comment: Which version? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case I've tracked this down to the interaction of modules.

**Do not use the "Login Destination"** module if you plan on using hook_user in your modules.

It bails out before all other modules may have had a chance to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a typo with the spelling of the "$caterogy" variable, but that shouldn't matter, since you're not using it in this test:

```
function favequest_favorites_user($op, &$edit, &$user, $caterogy=NULL) {
```

Using your code, I get four messages on login:

- load
- load
- login
- load

How about if you edit the user account? Do you get the "view" $op on the My Account page, and the "form" $op when you edit it?

Interesting that I don't get the "logout" $op when I log out--I assume that has something to do with a redirect, once I'm no longer authenticated.

Comment: Thank you for putting the time into trying to solve my problem. +1

Comment: about the non logout message -  it might be related to the anonymous cache.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have a drupal_goto after you login.
http://drupal.org/node/228688

About drupal_set_message - The messages are saved into the session. When you login the session gets reset, and that might be the reason you don't see them. For a quick debug I recommend using devel module with dd function or system log messages.

Adi

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: You are right. Actually I don't remember answering that question, but i'll edit my answer.